# Remove Parentheses from JSON Data in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to JQuery, json, etc..

I have some json data that I'm pulling into Jquery mobile / phone gap / dreamweaver from a site I dont manage. The JSON comes back like this:

```
({
  "status": "OK",
  "total": "1281",
  "people": [
    {
```

followed by all the data and then ends with:

```
    }
  ]
})
```

The parentheses will not allow my json query to display in the browser using a simple function:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('pageinit', '#more', function(){ 
            var url="http://www.somedata.com";
            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                //loop through deals
                $.each(json.people,function(i,dat){
                    $("#todaycal").append("<li>"+dat.name+"  "+dat.caseNo+"</li>");
                 });
                 $("#todaycal").listview('refresh');
            });
         });
    </script>
```

How do I remove the parentheses or "escape" it to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to access JSONP data.  You probably need to add `?callback=?` to your URL.

```
var url="http://www.somedata.com";
$.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(json){
    //loop through deals
    $.each(json.people,function(i,dat){
        $("#todaycal").append("<li>"+dat.name+"  "+dat.caseNo+"</li>");
    });
    $("#todaycal").listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who thought of JSONP.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I figured that's why there were `()`.  That it was expecting a callback and got nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're accessing a JSONP request, which should use a callback function. Usually the URL is formatted along the lines of `http://example.com/data.json?callback=foo`, and the data returned would be `foo({"foo":"bar","fizz":"buzz"})`. Those parens are probably added because the callback is being evaluated as an empty string.